# Handsontable hyperlink redirect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have loaded a handsontable and i have added it with hyperlink. But when i click on the hyperlink redirecting is not working.Please tell whether i have missed out something in my code..I am loading a set of values from java to handsontable ..

**Javascript Code**

```
headBuild.append("<a href='#'onclick='alertMenu(this);'>"
                        + cflowoutList.get(i).getCSD_OPER_GROUP() + "-"
                        + cflowoutList.get(i).getFOD_LVL_NAME() + "</a>" + ",");
```

**Handsontable**

```
function HeadRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
        var escaped = Handsontable.helper.stringify(value);
        escaped = strip_tags(escaped, '<em><b><strong><a><big>'); //be sure you only allow certain HTML tags to avoid XSS threats (you should also remove unwanted HTML attributes)
        td.style.textAlign="left"
        td.style.paddingLeft="1%";
        td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        td.style.fontSize="10px";
        td.style.fontFamily= 'verdana';
        td.style.background = '#EEFFF7';
        td.style.color = '#0B610B';
        td.innerHTML = escaped;
        return td;
    }
```

**CellProperties**

```
if($("#handsontable").handsontable('getData')[col,row][num_cols-1] ==="InHead"){
         cellProperties.renderer=inHeadRenderer;
        }
```

**Calling Primefaces remoteCommand**

```
function alertMenu(obj){
     var groupLabel=$(obj).text();
     grillDownForecast( [ { name : 'groupName',
                value : groupLabel }] );    
    }

<p:remoteCommand name="grillDownForecast"
                actionListener="#{Action.ActionBean.redirectDrillDown}" />
```

Comment: can we see a jsfiddle of this in action or your entire Handsontable initiation options? You set the renderer correctly but I don't think you're applying it to your cells the correct way.

Comment: Corrected the above code with answer.Thanks for the reply @ZekeDroid